# Does wire thickness matters for current only or for voltage as well?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, dc, wire

Suppose a wire capable to handle 10 amp current. Does it capable to handle 10 amp on specific voltage of on any voltage value?
Can same wire has different ratings for AC and DC ?

Comment: Within reason, it only matters for current. However, the insulation on the wire may have a voltage limit, and it could be different for AC and DC. Please note there are loose categories of voltage. Like 50V and under is low voltage, 50 to 100 is kind of medium, 100-500 or 600 is a high voltage, and after that you really need to be extremely careful. So don't try to use 48V wire intended for low-voltage lighting and run it on your solar panel array with Voc of 1000VDC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voltage rating of a wire depends on the insulation type and thickness, not on the conductor size.

Comment: You may wish to add an AC  skin effect comment for completeness. Or not :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: not, I think.  I also considered mentioning ampacity, cable in bundles, etc, but thought that was too much for the OP.